# In Unity3D, what ways can I improve the batching with a single texture atlas and four-point material?

Tags: c#, unity, batching

I'm building a randomized city terrain with a set of planes, custom 4 vertice square made in Blender. I've got a texture atlas working so that it draws on a single material and texture, but it's still hitting 97 batch calls when I render the layout. 4 of those are other things, leaving the ground resulting in 93 calls. Are there any other ways I can increase the efficiency? For the moment, the planes are created with a standard instantiate call:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < NumberOfTilesX; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < NumberOfTilesY; x++) {
            CityGround[i] = Instantiate(GroundTile, new Vector3(x, 0, y) * 6, GroundTile.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            CityGround[i].transform.parent = City.transform;
        }
    }
```

After being created, they set their own texture within the atlas using a random choice selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it supports this, although I don't know how to describe it in terms of where and what to click within Unity.

Using instancing:
Create a single, correctly-sized tile with 4 vertices (and 4 indices)

Edit: The index buffer is initialized and uploaded only once; it should be filled with the same 4 indices over and over, tileCount times. It's 16-bit-index size is (2 * 4 * tileCount) bytes. The vertex buffers will also be created and uploaded only once.

In addition to the per-vertex positions and UV's, send along per-instance world-translation and UV-translation vectors.

```
InputLayout
{
    {vector3 position, 0, per-vertex, 0}       //slot 0
    {vector2 UV, 0, per-vertex, 0}             //slot 0
    {vector3 worldOffset, 1, per-instance, 1}  //slot 1
    {vector2 UVOffset, 1, per-instance, 1}     //slot 1
}
```

Now, draw all tiles at once:

```
DrawIndexedInstanced(4, tileCount, 0, 0, 0);
```

That draws tileCount-instances, using the same 4 indices (and vertices) for each. After each tile is drawn, the per-instance data advances by 1, supplying the next tile's world and UV offsets.

The vertex shader would take the unit-tile-world-position and add the per-instance worldOffset before projection.

**Offloading more:**
Store only the "bottom-left corner" of each tile in a vertex along with the MIN and MAX UV coordinates. TileSize would presumably reside in a constant buffer. A geometry shader would spit out the original vertex plus the additional 3 indicated by TileSize as a finished, textured quad.

Since each tile(instance) can be re-constructed from a single vertex,

```
Draw(tileCount, 0);
```

is "instanced" and requires only a single bound vertex buffer.

```
InputLayout
{
    {vector3 oneCorner, 0, per-vertex, 0}  //slot 0
    {vector2 UV_Min, 0, per-vertex, 0}     //slot 0
    {vector2 UV_Max, 0, per-vertex, 0}     //slot 0
}
```

GS spits out a (right-handed) trianglestrip for each input vertex:

```
Vertex[0].Position = oneCorner;
Vertex[0].UV = (UV_Min.x, UV_Max.y);   //0,1
Vertex[1].Position = oneCorner + (0, 0, -g_TileSize.z);
Vertex[1].UV = (UV_Min.x, UV_Min.y);   //0,0
Vertex[2].Position = oneCorner + (g_TileSize.x, 0, -g_TileSize.z);
Vertex[2].UV = (UV_Max.x, UV_Min.y);   //1,0
Vertex[3].Position = oneCorner + (g_TileSize.x, 0, 0);
Vertex[3].UV = (UV_Max.x, UV_Max.y);   //1,1
```

**Thinking ahead:**

Then, by indexing these tile-in-one vertices, you can turn individual tiles on and off by re-uploading a new index buffer, leaving the "stale" vertices in place. Within the GS, you can also detect out-of-range/off-camera tiles and intentionally fail to emit any triangles for those tiles. This avoids having to sort the tiles on the CPU.

**Comment expansion:**

[image: vertex example]

VertexPolyline was named to be similar to VertexPosition, VertexPositionNormal, etc.
VertexPolyline is the data and is tightly packed into the VB.
The class which I instantiate, PolylineVertex, maintains a reference to the actual vertex, and only manipulates it; the only data an instance contains is the Index into the VB.
Index is only used for recycling vertices; I take that Index out of the index buffer and leave the dirty vertex buffer in place.
Multiple polylines can share the same PolylineVertex which allows them to communicate adjacency information, etc. (A lot of PolylineVertex was omitted)

FYI, I'm using all of the above to draw a bezier-based road system similar to SimCity.

```
g_d3dContext->DrawIndexed(s_allSegmentIndices.size(), 0, 0);
```

draws the entire road system in one call, using only VertexPolyline's. Also, the VB and IB are only uploaded when new segments are being created.

While a new segment is in edit-mode and draggable, I'm currently re-uploading the entire VB, which is inefficient. As an analogue to what you're facing, I'm currently refactoring the new-segment code to use it's own VB. When I'm finished, I will only have to re-upload 4 vertices while in edit-mode and only update the "master" buffer when a segment is finalized.

Comment: Everything I've presented regards the tiles only as data in buffers and not as "objects" that exist on the CPU. Using that idiom will help minimize state-changes and your class implementations will simplify down to wrappers that read/write to those vertices. It is similar to the pImpl idiom in that you are trying to maintain a distinct separation between the data and the implementation. Each idea presented above progressively reduces the amount of CPU-interaction required to achieve the same end-result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I actually came up with a solution almost identical. With a little work searching I uncovered old voxel engine code I had previously written and stored and modified it to fit the same purpose, generating a planar terrain in code. I'll still mark this as best, however!